# How can I use the name of outer table in subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

HEre is my query:

```
SET @date = '2019-02-12';

SELECT lds.product_id, sum(lds.amount) amount, lpp.price
FROM `log_daily_stock` lds
 JOIN (SELECT * FROM log_product_prices
       WHERE created_at <= @date
         AND product_id = lds.product_id          -- the problem is here
       ORDER BY created_at DESC) lpp
 ON lpp.product_id = lds.product_id
WHERE branch_id in (1,2)
  AND stock_date = @date
GROUP BY product_id, price
```

As I've commented in the query, `lds.product_id` is not known as a column and throws:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'lds.product_id' in 'where clause'

Any idea how can I fix it?

---

All I'm trying to do is getting is the newest price for the product. That's why I've ordered `created_at` as `DESC` and then `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: you don't need that condition in inner query at all. Jusr remove it and it'll work as expected.

Comment: lds is not an _outer_ table, it is on the same level.

Comment: @jarlh `lds` is an alias for `log_daily_stock` table.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Like (X) join (Y), none of them are outer.

Comment: @jarlh The scenario is: `X join (SELECT * FROM Y)`

Comment: Same thing. (X) or X doesn't matter.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  Non-working queries may not be good at communicating this information.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
SELECT lds.product_id, sum(lds.amount) amount, lpp.price
FROM `log_daily_stock` lds
 JOIN (SELECT * FROM log_product_prices
       WHERE created_at <= @date            
       ) lpp
 ON lpp.product_id = lds.product_id
WHERE branch_id in (1,2)
  AND stock_date = @date
GROUP BY lds.product_id, lpp.price
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT lds.product_id, sum(lds.amount) as amount, 
       (SELECT lpp.price
        FROM log_product_prices lpp
        WHERE lpp.created_at <= @date AND
              lpp.product_id = lds.product_id  
        ORDER BY created_at DESC
       ) as price_asof_date       
FROM `log_daily_stock` lds
WHERE branch_id in (1, 2) AND stock_date = @date
GROUP BY product_id, price
```